# How can Enable Cookies PhantomJs with php-webdrive

Tags: phantomjs, facebook-php-webdriver

I am using headless browser phantomjs how can enable cookies with Facebook php-webdriver

Code is bellow

```
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$host = 'http://localhost:8001';


$capabilities = array(
    WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0',
    'phantom.cookiesEnabled' => true,

);
```

'phantom.cookiesEnabled' => true, is not working.